# Apache Mesos Vs. Apache CloudStack

Tags: apache, openstack, mesos, apache-cloudstack

Managing the infrastructure (private cloud or public cloud) at scale and ease is addressed by Apache Mesos, Apache CloudStack and OpenStack.

I have few questions in this regard and wanted to see if someone can throw light.

1. Any article(s) that compares and contrast the above?
2. Why run one over the other at all? (as I see from tutorials that one can run over the other)
3. It seems like CloudStack is centered around VMs (Hypervisor) and Mesos is centered around Scheduling and allocation of resources in side VMs for different co-existing software systems.  Am I right in my conclusion?
4. If so, why does Mesos claims that it can manage bare metal boxes w/o even the need for Hypervisor?  Is this for the reason for workloads that do not go well with VMs? (esp. LSM based systems such as SOLR-Lucene and HBase)
5. Is it with the choice of Linux VMs. Vs. Linux Container for resource allocation? IOW, Mesos is Linux container based framework, and CloudStack is Linux VMs based framework?

Comment: Too broad, opinion-based, and off-topic for SO. Try Server Fault, and break this down so it isn't 5+ questions.

Comment: @chrylis - Thanks for the hint.  I have posted it on Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/questions/623803/apache-mesos-vs-apache-cloudstack).  They are all inter-related questions, hence the reason for combining.  Is there any way I can close this and redirect it to Server Fault one?